# Binary Search Not finding value in List

Tags: python, binary-search

Not sure what is going on with my code. I have a generic binary search function to return the position in a list. It works half the time.

I have a list with the contents:

```
['drag_part_num', 'sku', 'name', 'manufacturer', 'price', 'color', 'diameter', 'finish', 'made in the u.s.a.', 'material', 'model', 'position', 'specific application', 'style', 'type', 'width', 'att_fitment', 'thumbnail', 'small_image', 'image', 'media_gallery', 'type', 'simple_skus']
```

And this is my binary search:

```
def binary_search(self, a, x, lo=0, hi=None):   # can't use a to specify default for hi
    hi = hi if hi is not None else len(a) # hi defaults to len(a)   
    pos = bisect_left(a,x,lo,hi)          # find insertion position
    return (pos if pos != hi and a[pos] == x else -1) # don't walk off the end
```

When i run `print self.binary_search(headerList, 'color')`
It returns `-1`. I dont see how this is possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: You're not recursing and your array is not sorted. You might want to take another look at [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: WOW! lol I cant believe I over looked that.... kks changing the search fxn!

Answer (score 1):

For a binary search to work, the list needs to be sorted:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def binary_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):   # can't use a to specify default for hi
    hi = hi if hi is not None else len(a) # hi defaults to len(a)
    pos = bisect_left(a,x,lo,hi)          # find insertion position
    return (pos if pos != hi and a[pos] == x else -1) # don't walk off the end

header_list = sorted(['drag_part_num', 'sku', 'name', 'manufacturer', 'price',
                      'color', 'diameter', 'finish', 'made in the u.s.a.',
                      'material', 'model', 'position', 'specific application',
                      'style', 'type', 'width', 'att_fitment', 'thumbnail',
                      'small_image', 'image', 'media_gallery', 'type',
                      'simple_skus'])

print(header_list)
print(binary_search(header_list, 'color'))
```

Output:

```
['att_fitment', 'color', 'diameter', 'drag_part_num', 'finish', 'image',
 'made in the u.s.a.', 'manufacturer', 'material', 'media_gallery', 'model',
 'name', 'position', 'price', 'simple_skus', 'sku', 'small_image',
 'specific application', 'style', 'thumbnail', 'type', 'type', 'width']
1
```